# How to display legend in mapview when using cex argument

Tags: r, sp, mapview

Giving the example:

```
library(sp)
library(mapview)

data(meuse)
coordinates(meuse) <- ~x+y
proj4string(meuse) <- CRS("+init=epsg:28992")
mapview(meuse, cex = "cadmium", legend = TRUE)
```

I was expecting that `legend=TRUE` will display a legend with graduated circles, something similar like in this [link](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/173984/how-do-i-plot-points-as-graduated-proportional-circles-in-r). Is there a way to achieve this in `mapview`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can't be (easily) done with the current versions. `mapview` uses `leaflet::addLegend` which can only show a colour palette for a legend.

This issue has been sitting in the issue tracker since October 2016, so don't hold your breath waiting for it:

https://github.com/rstudio/leaflet/issues/316

and an earlier request from 2015, tagged P1, from 2015:

https://github.com/rstudio/leaflet/issues/111

Perhaps if you comment on those issues it might ping something at RStudio for them to implement it.